# Warning do PHP sem motivo aparente!

Tags: php, postgresql

Quero fazer uma conexão simples com o banco de dados mas cada vez que eu testo, após um longo carregamento da página me gera um Warning.

Arquivo banco.class.php:

```
<?php
abstract class banco
{
    public $servidor = "localhost";
    public $usuario = "postgres";
    public $porta = 80;
    public $senha = "senha5";
    public $nomebanco = "wmma";
    public $conexao = NULL;
    public $dataset = NULL;
    public $linhasafetadas = -1;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->conecta();
    }
    public function __destruct()
    {
        if($this->conexao != NULL){
            pg_close($this->conexao);
        }
    }

    public function conecta()
    {
        $this->conexao = pg_connect($this->servidor, $this->porta, $this->nomebanco, $this->usuario, $this->senha);
        echo "Método Conecta foi chamado corretamente" . $this->conexao;
    }
```

Arquivo teste.class.php:

```html
<?php
require_once("banco.class.php");
class teste extends banco
{

}
```

Arquivo teste.php:

```
require_once("classes/teste.class.php");
$testando = new teste();
```

---

Como resultado eu tenho o seguinte:

> Warning: pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: server
>   closed the connection unexpectedly This probaly means the server
>   terminated abnormally before or while processing the request. in ...
>   banco.class.php on line 37

Já reiniciei apache e o postgres, pensei que podia ser insistência na conexão, mas não resolveu.

Comment: o problema esta na função `pg_connect`  primeiro verifique se a extensão do php `php_pgsql.dll` esta habilitada, e se não for este o problema, tente utilizar apenas uma string `pg_connect('host=/tmp port=SUAPORTA dbname=SEUDB user=USER password=PASS');` com todos os parametros pre-configurados para ver se não e uma questão de montar a sua string

Comment: Você esta passando as informações do pg_connect como uma função com vários parametros, em vez disto você deve usar uma string, tente colocar `.` em vez de `,`

Comment: Troquei o código para o seguinte:
 **$this->conexao = pg_connect('host=/tmp. port=80. dbname=wmma. user=postgres. password=senha5');** e tive o mesmo resultado

Comment: Você esta concatenando errado, http://www.tiexpert.net/programacao/web/php/concatenacao-e-operacoes-matematicas.php

Comment: testa assim `pg_connect("host=ovelha port=80 dbname=wmma user=postgres password=senha5");`

Comment: Ainda na mesma @GabrielRodrigues :(

Comment: verificou se a extensão do php esta habilitada ?

Comment: positivo meu amigo! Tudo ok (Y)

Comment: O postgres não trabalha na porta 80

Comment: geralmente e a `5432` @rray

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues isso aí

Comment: BINGO! Vlw pessoal!
Ratiei nessa!

Comment: deu certo? se a portão é a padrão nem precisa informar